# yield * with generator function without yield

Tags: javascript, return, generator, yield

Here is my understanding on the exact mechanism of the `yield *` operator as opposed to the `yield` when I think of it after reading documentation and playing with it :

When calling `next()`on the iterator returned by a generator function, if it encounters :

- `yield someFunction()` : it should call `someFunction()` and return a pair object with its return value in `value` and whether there are more instructions to come in `done`
- `yield * someGenerator()` : it should use the iterator returned by `someGenerator()`, call the `next()` function on it and return a pair object with, the `value` that it got from the iterator, and `done` to `true` only if both the iterator returned `done===true` and that there are no more instructions to come

In other words, `yield *` delegates the next step of the iterator to another generator function.
**I would therefore expect that `someFunction()` being just a normal generator, it would pause its execution (and the one of its caller) even if it does not have a `yield` statement in it, but only a `return` statement or even no `return` statement at all.**

But it seems that it is not the case.

Have a look at this example where we use generators for a game flow, the goal being that each time we `yield`, we can pause the execution to send the new game state to the client, for instance. So the `mainGameFlow` generator will delegate to other generators just like function calls, but we want the execution being paused between each step :

```
function* mainGameFlow() {
  console.log('   (mainGameFlow) Will give money')
  yield* giveMoney()
  console.log('   (mainGameFlow) Will give card')
  yield* giveCard()
}

function* giveMoney() {
  console.log('      (giveMoney) Giving money to player')
}

function* giveCard() {
  console.log('      (giveCard) Giving card to player')
  // if(card has effect)...
  console.log('      (giveCard) Will apply card\'s effects')
  yield* applyCardEffect()
}

function* applyCardEffect() {
  console.log('         (applyCardEffect) Applying card effect')
}

console.log('Will get iterator from generator')
const iterator = mainGameFlow()
console.log('Will launch iterator first step')
iterator.next()
console.log('Iterator paused')
```

I would expect that the first call to `next()` on the `mainGameFlow` iterator would pause its execution just after the logging of 'Giving money to player'. Because when a generator just returns, it stops its flow just like when it yields.
But here instead, all the logging lines are reached and the main iterator is paused only after the whole flow happened.

My question is : do you think there is a problem in my code ? If not, do you know a better documentation than the MDN on `yield *` that would clearly make understandable why the flow continues in this use case ?

Comment: The generator function runs on the first next() call to the first yield or return statement. And as you said "yield* delegates the next step of the iterator to another generator function."

Comment: It might be a bit easier to understand if you think of yield and return as producers and .next() as consumer. Every consumption matches exactly one production.

Comment: "*`someFunction()` being just a normal generator*" - did you mean `someGenerator()`?

Answer (score 2):

This section on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) explains it nicely (read the third point):

> Once paused on a yield expression, the generator's code execution
> remains paused until the generator's next() method is called. Each
> time the generator's next() method is called, the generator resumes
> execution, and runs until it reaches one of the following:
>
> - A yield, which causes the generator to once again pause and return    the generator's new value. The next time next() is called, execution
>   resumes with the statement immediately after the yield.
> - throw is used to throw an exception from the generator. This halts    execution of the generator entirely, and execution resumes in the
>   caller (as is normally the case when an exception is thrown).
> - **The end of the generator function is reached. In this case, execution    of the generator ends and an IteratorResult is returned
>   to the caller    in which the value is undefined and done is true.**
> - A return statement is reached. In this case, execution of the    generator ends and an IteratorResult is returned to the caller in
>   which the value is the value specified by the return statement and
>   done is true.

The `yield *` expression is used with generator functions or iterables.
If the iterable is empty or the generator function has no `yield` keyword, the iterator returned from the main generator function call will be completed with the first call to `next()` and will never pause in between the `yield *` calls.

```js
function* parentGenerator(){
  console.log("parentGenerator:: start");
  yield* childGeneratorOne();
  yield* childGeneratorTwo();
  console.log("parentGenerator:: end");
}

function* childGeneratorOne(){
  //does not yield a value, so it is complete
  console.log("childGeneratorOne:: start");
}

function* childGeneratorTwo(){
  //does not yield a value, so it is complete
  console.log("childGeneratorTwo:: start");
}

const itr = parentGenerator();
console.log(itr.next());
```

So in your case, when you invoke the `mainGameFlow()` generator function, the control goes to the `giveMoney()` generator function with the help of `yield *` expression, which has no `yield` keyword.

It returns an `IteratorResult` where the `value` is `undefined` and `done` is `true` and hence is never paused and goes on to the next line of execution.

The same happens with `giveCard()` call, which also returns an `IteratorResult` which has an `undefined` as the `value` and `done` is `true`, so the function never pauses and runs to completion, as in all cases `done` is true.

You can test this theory by placing a `yield 1` in your `giveMoney()` generator function. The main generator function will be paused until you call `next()` again, this is because the result from the `giveMoney()` is `{ value: 1, done: false}` and it is paused until `done` is `true`:

```js
function* mainGameFlow() {
  console.log('   (mainGameFlow) Will give money')
  yield* giveMoney()
  console.log('   (mainGameFlow) Will give card')
  yield* giveCard()
}

function* giveMoney() {
  console.log('      (giveMoney) Giving money to player')
  //paused here until next() is called again
  yield 1;
}

function* giveCard() {
  console.log('      (giveCard) Giving card to player')
  console.log('      (giveCard) Will apply card\'s effects')
  yield* applyCardEffect()
}

function* applyCardEffect() {
  console.log('         (applyCardEffect) Applying card effect')
}

console.log('Will get iterator from generator')
const iterator = mainGameFlow()
console.log('Will launch iterator first step')
iterator.next()
console.log('Iterator paused')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would expect that the first call to `next()` on the `mainGameFlow` iterator would pause its execution just after the logging of 'Giving money to player'. Because when a generator just returns, it stops its flow just like when it yields

Yes - the `giveMoney()` generator that encountered the `return` statement *does* stop. But the outer generator, `iterator`, still needs to produce a value - and since `giveMoney()` is done, the `yield*` statement resumes the execution of the `mainGameFlow` code, to run until it meets the next `yield` statement.